# Save state of TextView and Spinner inside of CustomView

Tags: android

I have 3 custom views.
The first one works great.  It contains an EditText when I launch an intent and come back whatever the user entered is restored.

The 2nd contains a TextView and the 3rd a Spinner.  They do not save when I launch my intent and return.

I think know how to preserve the data using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState in my custom views, However when the activity containing the custom views is not killed (meaning it is only paused), and I return onRestoreInstanceState is not called.

This is what I'm calling in my custom views when I need to save them.

```
    @Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    textValue = editText.getText().toString();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("instanceState", super.onSaveInstanceState());
    bundle.putString(TEXT_VALUE_KEY, this.textValue);

    return bundle;
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (state instanceof Bundle) {
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        textValue = bundle.getString(TEXT_VALUE_KEY);
        editText.setText(textValue);
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable("instanceState"));
        return;
    }

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```

I'm unsure I what I should do since onRestoreInstanceState is not called.  I think the EditText customView works because default android behavior saved them temporarily, but it doesn't save spinners or TextViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `onCreate()` method in order to check if the `Activity` has already called `onSavedInstanceState` like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        // The activity haven't called onSavedInstanceState(), which means you should initialize your objects and UI here
    }
    else {
        // Whatever states you saved onSavedInstanceState() are stored in savedInstaceState, so use them to reconstruct your customViews
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding Christopher,  I think I figured it out.  I have a .configure method in my custom views that I was calling from onResume in my fragment.  It had a statement that was clearing the values I needed.  However, the main issue I was having is that in the cases where I would have problems only onResume would be called.  No onCreate or onRestoreInstanceState.  However since I was doing it wrong, I'm not sure there needs to be solution to the my scenario.

Comment: I understand. I have a hunch that maybe if you call the configure method from the onCreate, instead of onResume, it could maintain its state. If not, Try configuring your fragments on their onCreateView, since they natively maintain their states, they should be rebuilt by themselves after onResume is called

Comment: Hi Christopher, I apologize for not responding sooner.  I had to take a day away from my project.  I think you're exactly right on resume is called every time you return and in general "Configuring" should not take place every time since it should already be configured.  I came to the same conclusion you just gave me "Try to configure your fragments on their onCreateView."  Funny how things work better if you use tools as they were intended.  I marked your answer as the accepted answer, as it addressed the issue.  My original question is irrelevant.  Many thanks for the help.